# Django - Changing the url to redirect from a middleware on the fly

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on

I'm building a SSO login meant to be used from links send by emails.

Each link should auto-connect the user (SSO), and be clickable multiple times (they have a TTL, which depends on the email)

It works fine, but I'm concerned about the end-user sharing his url on social networks (basically copy/pasting the url, which contains the SSO token), allowing anyone following the link to be logged in automatically.

My first attempt was to try to remove the GET SSO_TOKEN parameter, from my SSOMiddleware, as follow:

```
if remove_token_middleware:
  request.GET._mutable = True  # GET is not mutable by default, we force it
  # Remove the token from the url to avoid displaying it to the client (avoids sharing sso token when copy/pasting url)
  del request.GET[SSO_TOKEN_PARAM]
  request.GET._mutable = False  # Restore default mutability

return login(request, user) if service.get("auto_auth") else None
```

Basically, my thought was that since the SSO_TOKEN is in the `request.get` object, removing it from it would eventually change the url where the user gets redirected

In my controller, here is how the user gets "redirected" (using `render`)

```
return render(request, 'campagne_emprunt/liste_offres_prets.html', locals())
```

When using `render`, there is no redirection, and the SSO token is still visible in the URL (in the browser address bar).

Is there a way to somehow tell Django to change the destination url, on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

So in order to redirect, there is a builtin redirect function of Django that you use **instead** of rendering I think .. give it a shot,

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def redirect_view(request):
    response = redirect('/redirect-success/')
    return response
```

and for reference-
https://realpython.com/django-redirects/

Comment: I know about that, but that would require me to change every single render() to redirect() and they don't have the same usage, `render` provides locals to be sent to the template, while `redirect` doesn't show a template, but call a controller instead. Maybe a better approach would be for the links with SSO to always link toward the same controller (centralisation) and then that controller would redirect to the right controller (without the token), which would then render the view.